# Setting fixed column width does not work with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have a table created using HTML and Bootstrap 3 like in the following example.

Even if I set a fixed column width through the width attribute in the colgroup this is not applied and I am not able to set a column width at all here.

Can someone tell me if this needs to be done differently when using Bootstrap 3 or if I am missing something else here?
In this case I want to set the column width of a specific column (here the 3rd one) to 70px.

**Example table:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive tableDT">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col width="70px" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tag</th>
            <th>No. of Items</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some number</td>
            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>View</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Put the width on the `<th>` element. The "width" attribute of the `<col>` element is obsolete. (Better yet, use CSS.)

Comment: Thanks, this does not seem to make a difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use 'px'. you just give it as `width="70"`
you can do it in css as well as:

`colgroup col:last-child{
   width: 70px;
 }`

Comment: That was it - thanks a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)